# How do Adparams works in Google Adwords PHP api

Tags: google-ads-api

I have 700 products to create ads each with different cost and year of make and i want to display this values in my ad and change them dynamically. so i have used adparams in the headline and in description1 as

```
$textAd->headline     = 'Sale!  productname {param1:2011}';
$textAd->description1 = 'For Just ${param2:25000}';
```

as descried in the forums. and i have created set the adparams to the keywords.

```
$adParam1 = new AdParam($adGroupId, $keywordId, $year, 1);
$adParam2 = new AdParam($adGroupId, $keywordId, $price, 2);

// Create operations.
$adParamOperation1 = new AdParamOperation();
$adParamOperation1->operand = $adParam1;
$adParamOperation1->operator = 'SET';

$adParamOperation2 = new AdParamOperation();
$adParamOperation2->operand = $adParam2;
$adParamOperation2->operator = 'SET';
```

since adparams is related to keywords and keywords related to adgroup and not ads, I have created adgroup for each ad(so that i have 700 adgroups). And each adgroup has a Ad with a related keyword. Now when i get the ads using the api.

I get something like this

```
........
[ad] => TextAd Object
(
     [headline] => Sale! product {param1:2011}
     [description1] =>  Just ${param2:25000}
.........
```

the param strings are shown as such, i could not determine whether the adparams, works correctly and also im not confident that i'm in the right path. Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Ad params are keyword level, and adverts are adgroups based.
If your Adwords account is structure correctly, there shouldn't Be any issues here.

The advert will always look like it does above (with {param1:default} etc) in editor and online, but the actual advert displayed on google search would contain the params you set on the keyword. If no pram is set, it would default to the value inside the bracket.

From my experience of using ad params, it was more complicated as our ppc staff couldn't change adverts through Adwords editor which caused more issues.

Another method, is to simply delete old adverts (which are never really deleted) and create new ones on any change.

The main benefit of ad params, is the data collection is consistent when changing the content of the params. Where as changing the actual adverts completely removes all historic data.

Hope that helps.